# How to avoid downloading image from firebase if i have already downloaded previously?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store image from firebase database and named it FirebaseuniqUserID.jpeg.(like buwkgefuikbuifbkc8gfybfy.jpeg). And user can change image anytime.
For getting image link from firebase realtime database i used addListenerForSingleValueEvent.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseuniqUserID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //here i am downloading image//
        //and named it FirebaseuniqUserID.jpeg
    }
```

Now the problem is this when this listener is called every time image is download.
But now i want avoid downloading if current user has latest updated image of user in firebase to reduce firebase downloaded data.

Comment: what is your logic to decide image is updated or not in firebase?

Comment: Yeh bro,you catch the thing which i need that how i prepare this logic to avoid downloading in firebase also.?

Comment: "User"node is like      https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+user&client=ms-android-xiaomi&prmd=vin&sxsrf=ACYBGNS7bHODJ4YE5Pdf2a5sS9mKexJm4Q:1572208453461&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFlobzpL3lAhUBvo8KHcRaDtsQ_AUoAnoECA0QAg&biw=360&bih=559&dpr=2#imgrc=Aokl23GMJOdzOM&imgdii=1ZiZTx-DNr5k6M

Answer (score 0):

> I want avoid downloading if current user has latest updated image of user in Firebase

To solve this, I definitely recommend you to use an image loading and caching library. For Android we have [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

> Glide is a fast and efficient open source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and **disk caching**, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different options, first is [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and 2nd is that, you can save image downloading status in your local database file or SharePreferences. But image cache is the best solution.