# How to link image from storage to real time database (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question about how to link images to each object from the real-time database.

I have RecyclerView in my app that contains all objects from Firebase database.

The Object contain lampTitle, lampDesc, lampType.

[image]
In firebase storage I have 3 images that should be shown under each object in Recycler view.
Each image should match his object.
For example. air_conditioning.png should be with AirCondition object, etc...

[image]
That what i have for now:

My LightsFragment - contain recycler view:

```
public class LightsFragment extends Fragment implements LightsPresenter {

    private RecyclerView RVLights;
    private ArrayList<Light> lights = new ArrayList<>();
    private Light light;
    private LightsAdapter lightsAdapter;
    private LightsView presenter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lights, container, false);
        presenter = new LightsView(lights, light, this);
        RVLights = view.findViewById(R.id.RVLights);
        presenter.loadData();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter() {
        lightsAdapter = new LightsAdapter(getActivity(), lights);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        RVLights.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RVLights.setAdapter(lightsAdapter);
    }
```

LightsAdapter:

```
public class LightsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LightsAdapter.LightsViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Light> lights;

    public LightsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Light> lights) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lights = lights;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public LightsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lights_item, parent, false);
        return new LightsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LightsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Light light = lights.get(position);
        holder.TVlightTitle.setText(light.getLampTitle());
        holder.TVLightDesc.setText(light.getLampDesc());
        holder.TVLightType.setText(String.valueOf(light.getLampType()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lights.size();
    }

    public class LightsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView TVlightTitle;
        private TextView TVLightDesc;
        private TextView TVLightType;
        private ImageView IVLightImage;

        public LightsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            TVlightTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lightTitle);
            TVLightDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lightDesc);
            TVLightType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lightType);
            IVLightImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lightImage);
        }
    }
```

Light class:

```
public class Light {

    private int lampType;
    private String lampTitle;
    private String lampDesc;

    public Light(String lampDesc, String lampTitle, int lampType) {
        this.lampType = lampType;
        this.lampTitle = lampTitle;
        this.lampDesc = lampDesc;
    }

    public Light() {
    }

    public int getLampType() {
        return lampType;
    }

    public void setLampType(int lampType) {
        this.lampType = lampType;
    }

    public String getLampTitle() {
        return lampTitle;
    }

    public void setLampTitle(String lampTitle) {
        this.lampTitle = lampTitle;
    }

    public String getLampDesc() {
        return lampDesc;
    }

    public void setLampDesc(String lampDesc) {
        this.lampDesc = lampDesc;
    }

}
```

Lights presenter and view:

```
public interface LightsPresenter {

    void setAdapter();

}

public class LightsView {

    private ArrayList<Light> lights = new ArrayList<>();
    private Light light;
    private FirebaseDatabase db;
    private DatabaseReference allLights;
    private LightsPresenter lightsPresenter;

    public LightsView(ArrayList<Light> lights, Light light, LightsPresenter lightsPresenter) {
        this.lights = lights;
        this.light = light;
        this.lightsPresenter = lightsPresenter;
    }

    public void loadData() {
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        allLights = db.getReference("AllLights");

        allLights.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    light = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Light.class);
                    lights.add(light);
                    Log.i("LightsDataLoaded", "true " + light.getLampTitle());
                }
                lightsPresenter.setAdapter();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i("LightsDataLoaded", "false ");

            }
        });
    }

}
```

That what I have in result :

[image]

Comment: Show your image upload and database insertion code. If you upload image manually you have to pass the storage location in realtime database

Comment: Hi @Ashish, I'm uploaded images manually to storage , and added path to real time data base.
I tried to use glide in the adapter to load the URL.
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LightsViewHolder holder, int position) { final Light light = lights.get(position); holder.TVlightTitle.setText(light.getLampTitle()); holder.TVLightDesc.setText(light.getLampDesc()); holder.TVLightType.setText(String.valueOf(light.getLampType())); Glide.with(context) .load(light.getLampImageUrl()) .into(holder.IVLightImage); }

Still not working

Comment: Hi Michael,  You already posted this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647082/how-to-link-images-from-firebase-storage-to-a-firebase-real-time-database and it was closed.  Generally its better to edit the original question so that a reopen vote will be created than to create a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to match something, you should simply store the image url under each object:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- AllLights
          |
          --- AirBag
                |
                --- lampDesc: "Is it safe..."
                |
                --- lampTitle: "Air bag Lamp"
                |
                --- lampType: 1
                |
                --- lampImageUrl: "Firebase Storage Image Url" //New property added
```

As you can see I have added a new property that should hold the url of the corresponding image. In the end, you can simply use [Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58589011/5246885) to display it.

Comment: Thank for you'r answer.
I have added glide to grade.app and trying to do something like that.
In my adapter , under onBindView I added :

   ' public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LightsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Light light = lights.get(position);
        holder.TVlightTitle.setText(light.getLampTitle());
        holder.TVLightDesc.setText(light.getLampDesc());
        holder.TVLightType.setText(String.valueOf(light.getLampType()));
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(light.getLampImageUrl())
                .into(holder.IVLightImage);
    }'

Comment: But it still not shown the image.
On debugging i see the storage url.

Comment: It sounds like you should ask another question that explains what isn't working the way you expect in case of Glide. Add also its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in this way, me and other Firebase developers can help you.